# MySQL + PHP -- User Authentication Levels

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm trying to build a website with a front-end user account system, and a back-end system where only people with access_level in the MySQL database have a level of 1 versus 0 (the default client access level) if my code looks like the following, what do I need to do to only allow users with access level 1 access the page?

```
<?php
require("../../includes/common.php"); 
if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) 
{ 
    header("Location: login.php"); 
    die("Redirecting to login.php"); 
} 
?>
```

Comment: query db for * records where username & password meet

Comment: Well.. You need to get the users name, and check the database to see what value is associated with it. You can then set a session variable to that value. At the top of the page that you want to filter users on, have an if statement that will only display the page if the session variable has a value of 1.

Comment: then add the column key to a $_SESSION, then call an if ($_SESSION['columnname') === 1) { } else {...}

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have $_SESSION['access_level'] in your session then you can

```
if(empty($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['access_level'] != 1) 
{ 
  header("Location: login.php"); 
  die("Redirecting to login.php"); 
}
```